# Generate a random neutrally stable matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I need to generate random real matrices such that all eigenvalues have real part equal to 0 -- i.e. random neutrally stable matrices. What's the simplest way to do this? Note that I don't care about the resulting distribution other than that no neutrally stable matrices should be "left out". In other words I need a surjective function.

One way would be to compute a random matrix $B$, then form $B-B^T$. But that isn't surjective. :(

Comment: What does "neutrally stable" mean?

Comment: All eigenvalues have zero real part. :)

Comment: Do you want real matrices?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just realised my answer was wrong. I'll heavily edit it; until then, it'll stay deleted.

Comment: Yes, real matrices. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a random matrix is "always" diagonalizable. Thus you can proceed as follows. If $n=2p$ or $n=2p+1$, then we consider $p$ i.i.d. variables following $N(0,1)$: $a_1,\cdots,a_p$ and a random matrix (clearly "always" invertible) $P=[p_{i,j}]\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ where the $(p_{i,j})$ are also iid variables following $N(0,1)$. Now we put $U_i=\begin{pmatrix}0&-a_i\\a_i&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $A=PDP^{-1}$ where $D=diag(U_1,\cdots,U_p)$ if $n=2p$ and $D=diag(U_1,\cdots,U_p,0)$ if $n=2p+1$.

Comment: Looks right! Thanks!